# ¿Cómo usar la funcion preProcess para imputar datos en una variable?

Tags: r, machine-learning

Estoy trabajando en el conocido dataset de Titanic de kaggle, utilizando el paquete caret.

Para la variable "Embarked", aparecen dos registros cuyo valor es ".

```
    table(data$Embarked)


  "  C"  Q"  S" 
  2 168  77 644
```

Intentando filtrar esos caracteres, veo que los registros 62 y 830, son las líneas que tengo que modificar.

```
    data%>%
  filter(data$Embarked=="\"")

"62 1   1   ""Icard Miss. Amelie""  female  38  0   0   113572  
"830    1   1   ""Stone Mrs. George Nelson (Martha Evelyn)""    female  62
```

Cuando lo intento modificar con diversas técnicas, para marcarlos como NA y poder manipularlos, no me lo permite, así que he anulado los registros, aunque no es lo más recomendable, con la siguiente función:

```
data2<-data[-c(62,830), ]
```

Vamos a ver cuántas variables tengo tipo NA:

```
apply(is.na(data),2,sum)
```

Me aparecen muchísimos registros sin datos para la variable Edad y Cabina.

PassengerId    Survived      Pclass        Name     Surname         Sex         Age       SibSp       Parch      Ticket        Fare
0           0           0           0           0           0         177           0           0           0           0
Cabin    Embarked
687           0

Voy a obviar la variable Cabina y a convertir en variables dummy el resto de variables categóricas.

```
data2$Survived<-as.factor(data2$Survived)
data2$Pclass<-as.factor(data2$Pclass)
data2$is_age_missing<-as.factor(data2$is_age_missing)
as.numeric(data2$Fare)
```

Comprobamos que efectivamente se han modificado.

```
is.factor(data2$Survived)
is.factor(data2$Pclass)
is.factor(data2$is_age_missing)
is.numeric(data2$Fare)
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
```

Hacemos un subset con las variables que nos interesan:

```
traintitanic2<-subset(data2,select=c(Survived,Pclass,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Fare,Embarked,is_age_missing,travelers))
```

Posteriormente, continuando con el ejercicio, he transformado las variables categóricas en variables dummy númericas, tipo 0-1. (, sin mayor tipo de problema,

```
    dummy<-dummyVars(~.,data=traintitanic2[,-1])


    dummy_train<-predict(dummy,traintitanic2[,-1])

    head(dummy_train)

  Pclass.1 Pclass.2 Pclass.3 Sexfemale Sexmale Age SibSp Parch      Fare EmbarkedC" EmbarkedQ" EmbarkedS" is_age_missing.0
1        0        0        1         0       1  22     1     0      7.25          0          0          1                1
2        1        0        0         1       0  38     1     0 712833.00          1          0          0                1
3        0        0        1         1       0  26     0     0   7925.00          0          0          1                1
4        1        0        0         1       0  35     1     0     53.10          0          0          1                1
5        0        0        1         0       1  35     0     0      8.05          0          0          1                1
6        0        0        1         0       1  NA     0     0  84583.00          0          1          0                0
  is_age_missing.1 travelers
1                0         2
2                0         2
3                0         1
4                0         2
5                0         1
6                1         1
```

pero cuando intento hacer el preproceso para imputar las variables que faltan en el dataset me da error.

```
pre.process<-preProcess(dummy_train,method="bagImpute")
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:10: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
1: EmbarkedC" ~.
^
10.
str2lang(x)
9.
formula.character(object, env = baseenv())
8.
formula(object, env = baseenv())
7.
as.formula(paste(var, "~."))
6.
bagging.data.frame(as.formula(paste(var, "~.")), data = x, nbagg = B, 
x = FALSE, keepX = FALSE)
5.
ipred::bagging(as.formula(paste(var, "~.")), data = x, nbagg = B, 
x = FALSE, keepX = FALSE)
4.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
3.
lapply(bagModels, bagImp, x = x)
2.
preProcess.default(dummy_train, method = "bagImpute")
1.
preProcess(dummy_train, method = "bagImpute")
```

Comment: ¿Esto en qué lenguaje está hecho? Ponlo como etiqueta, por favor

Comment: R. Se me paso la etiqueta :)

Comment: Al utilizar el dataset de este link, no me aparece este problema. Quizás puedes probar con este dataset https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/vinicius150987/titanic3